# How was asp.Net mvc tightly coupled with IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Nobody here on stackoverflow dared to answer this question
[How is an ASP.NET MVC application heavily dependent on System.Web assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645655/how-is-an-asp-net-mvc-application-heavily-dependent-on-system-web-assembly)

Some commented that System.web is related to Asp.Net and not IIS, so why can't we host asp.net mvc app on other webservers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is an ASP.NET MVC application heavily dependent on System.Web assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645655/how-is-an-asp-net-mvc-application-heavily-dependent-on-system-web-assembly)

Comment: in system.web there are http handlers in place for asp.net and mvc pipelines while we can also write our own custom http handlers but there are some conventions in asp.net and mvc which are cooked inside the system.web dll

Comment: @Tom W , you gave the same link what is already there on question.

Comment: Yes, because it answers the question.

Comment: Why do you think you can't host asp.net MVC on other webservers?

Comment: @Tom W, that is what i am asking.

Comment: I mean, a web server is a computer. If you write some code in say phyton for hte server code, and the web server does not support that language, then you can't run it. There is no such thing as JUST tossing a web application and system on to ANY OLD server. I mean, if the site runs MySQL, and you write using oracle? Then your app can't use that web server, can it? I mean, this is ZERO different then say trying to run windows software on a Mac computer. ANY code library you adopt for ANY web server means that the web server MUST have that code support. This holds true for ALL web servers.

Comment: If you thus write c# code and use .net code behind? Then without question that web site will require those external libraries and systems. As noted, this holds true for any desktop computer, or any web server. The code, the libraries and what you use to write that code thus means you MUST have that code and library support on that system. As others stated, there are versions of .net that now run say on Linux, and thus you can run such sites based on .net coding approaches. I mean, if you use Apache web server, then you limited to its features. If you use IIS, then you limited to its features.

Comment: Thanks, @AlbertD.Kallal, can you please tell me what were those .Net Framework things that heavily depend on IIS, and Microsoft had no choice but to launch.Net Core/5+

Comment: They don't depend on IIS, IIS depends on .net to run! Using Apache, or IBM WebSphere web server? What do THEY depend on? Why of course code libraries and languages that the web server in question was built with. I mean, what languages and libraries does Excel depend on? (answer: code libraries Excel was built with). How this works for Excel, or some web server is the same. Since IIS was built using a lot of .net framework, then that's what it requires. What code libraries and systems the web server was built with does not necessary mean  web site built needs to use those libraries, does it?

Comment: All 3 of the noted web servers can accept post/get requests and spit out HTML pages for the web browser to use. At that point, you don't have to care or know what the web server was built on. The grey part becomes is web site built with more then just HTML code? Unless that web server supports using python or whatever float your boat development language? then yes, the web server will have to support interaction with that code system in question. But this is the SAME requirement for all web servers. So what the site was built with is what matters more then what the web server was built with

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, again thank you so much for the reply, appreciate it. Can you please answer it in the answer section so that I could accept it, and with some examples, like this and that component of Asp.net Framework are initiated by IIS, so we were bound to use IIS as a webserver, otherwise other web servers were always cheaper than windows hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the question in comments ask how does .net depend on IIS?

It does not! IIS depend on .net, and parts were created with .net!!

so .net does not depend on IIS, IIS depends on .net to run!

Using Apache, or IBM WebSphere web server? What do THEY depend on? Why of course code libraries and languages that the web server in question was built with.

I mean, what languages and libraries does Excel depend on? (answer: code libraries Excel was built with). How this works for Excel, or some web server is the same.

Since IIS was built using a lot of .net framework, then that's what it requires.

there is no depednance on .net to IIS, it is the other way around.

So what code libraries and systems the web server was built with does not necessary mean web site built needs to use those libraries.

All 3 web servers (Apache, IBM WebSphere, IIS) can handle basic HTML sites, and can accept standard web requests.

And they ALL MUST spit out 100% HTML standard pages for any browser to consume.

However, we are confusing what the web site server system was built with vs that of what the developer built the web site with!!!

The fact that the web server was written in c++, or parts by .net, or PHP for Apache?

We don't care much.

However, if I build a site that uses MySQL, then obvislty that site not going to work on a hosted server that don't have the oracle database system.

So, one has to either:

```
use the developer tools and support of what the web server has

or

pick your web development tools and FIND a web server system that supports that choice.
```

Unless that web server supports using python or whatever float your boat development language? then yes, the web server will have to support interaction with that code system in question. But this is the SAME requirement for all web servers.

So what the site was built with is what matters MORE then what the web server was built with.

I mean, one could create a 100% compatible web server in assembler, c++ or BASIC.

Where thing become specific is what develpment cycle and systems does that web server support? In the case of sites built using .net?

There is no real requirement that the web server having been built with the .net framework, but that server and site in question would certainly require the ability to consume .net code.

When you create a .net site, and publish? All of the .net source code is compiled down into .net .dll's. So at the very least, that web server would have to support calls to those .dll's, and they require the .net frame work. This does not mean that the web server has to been built using .net framework, but it DOES mean that the server in question would have to support calling .net assemblies as .dll's.

Further more, all web servers have quite a few specific systems, and security and authentication is one such area. So, if a developer adopts a particular security model, then it is VERY doubt full that say Apache would support the same security and configerations as compared to IIS.

And often parts of the web application will of course call + use and interact with those web server security features, or even general purpose libaries that are included as part of that web server.

So, the windows version of Excel no more runs on a Mac, or Andriod phone then does any web site developed to a specific set of standards.

But, at the end of the day?

The web server depends on .net code, not that the .net framework as ANYTHING at all to do with depending on IIS. IT is in fact quite much the other way around.

This is really not a whole lot different then suggesting that Excel should be able to read and use power-point files. there are differences here.

Web sites development NEVER allowed any old web site to be just tossed up to some web server and we can expect it to run.

In this regards, if you going to use Excel on your desktop, you need Excel installed. A web server is JUST a computer, and any code and things you use on that computer thus have to be installed and supported on that computer.

So, while for example you can run .net code on Linux, a web site developed for IBM's WebSphere, for Apache, or for ISS are all going to be different and certainly such webs sites would not be interchangeable, or compatible with each other, no more so then the windows version of Excel is the same as the Android or Mac version.

In fact, how quite much any desktop software works? Well that software only works and runs on a desktop computer that supports that software. And a web server is identical in this regards - it can only run software that 100% compatible with that given server and setup.

In summary?
How this works is quite much how all computers worked from day one of the PC revolution we are all part of.

> > with some examples, like this and that component of Asp.net Framework are initiated by IIS, s

Well, how any .dll is loaded and called works quite much the same here.

The new .net core? All that newer framework is a .net runtime system that is NOT dependent on the windows api and platform. From a developer point of view, using .net core vs older .net framework? You don't notice the difference, but that .net runtime (core) removed dependencies on windows.

So just like the Java engine can run on anything from a phone to a server? The same goes for the .net core. It should be able to run on any computer - even Android phones. so the newer .net core is simple a re-vamped .net runtime system that is far more platform neutral.

The whole idea of the .net framework was much like the Java engine. They could re-build the .net interpreter to run on any platform, and thus code built around .net in theory could run on any computer - not just windows. But of course the .net framework is quite heavy dependent on the windows API and platform. The re-vamped .net core removes those dependences.

thus, in theory, any software written using .net core is in theory multi-platform and quite "OS" neutral. When it comes to desktop software, that's somewhat doubtful this can be done, but with web based? yes, that goal is quite easy since the other end to render the output is based on industry standards (HTML - and now web assembly).

Answer (score 1):

"Why can't we host ASP.NET MVC on other web servers" is an invalid statement because you can definitely run such web apps on other web servers, like Apache/nginx/Jexus and more, with some help from Mono, which provides,

- An open source `System.Web` implementation.
- FastCGI daemon to integrate with all compliant web servers.

However, if you want to host your production web apps, this approach is not realistic compared to using .NET Framework/IIS/Windows from Microsoft, because you need to support yourself on Mono issues because it is not as solid as .NET Framework (and its `System.Web` is complete).

ASP.NET Core is the right way to go at this moment.

Comment: my question is all about the system.web, does it depend on IIS heavily?

Comment: @AashimaKhatoon If you can run `System.Web` with other web servers, then the answer is also clear that it does not rely on IIS.

Comment: @Ashima No it does not. Instead, you should say that "IIS depends on System.Web heavily in order to process ASP.NET (and MVC) request". Any web server that can process ASP.NET (and MVC) request pipeline can host ASP.NET application, such as NGINX+FastCGI (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/nginx/)